# Bower not installing from bower.json

Tags: node.js, git, proxy, bower

I'm stuck in corporate firewall / proxy hell... I'm trying to install my dependencies from my bower.json file but am hitting this error:

```
bower jquery#~2.1.1            ECMDERR Failed to execute "git ls-remote --tags --heads https://github.com/jquery/jquery.git", exit code of #128

Additional error details:
fatal: unable to access 'https://github.com/jquery/jquery.git/': Failed connect to github.com:443; No error
```

I've Google'd this and found plenty of answers, and tried the following, but none seem to fix mine.

I've set my `git config` with the following:

```
url.http://.insteadof=git://
url.https://.insteadof=git://
```

and I use CNTLM to manage my proxy credentials so my proxy settings looks like:

```
http.proxy=http://127.0.0.1:53128/
https.proxy=http://127.0.0.1:53128/
```

the following in my NPM config:

```
http_proxy = "http://127.0.0.1:53128/"
https-proxy = "http://127.0.0.1:53128/"
https_proxy = "http://127.0.0.1:53128"
proxy = "http://127.0.0.1:53128/"
registry = "http://registry.npmjs.org/"
strict-ssl = false
```

and I've set the following in my .bowerrc file:

```
"proxy":"http://127.0.0.1:53128",
"https-proxy":"http://127.0.0.1:53128",
"strict-ssl":false
```

I think that's everything, I get a similar error message when I try `bower list`.

All my Git commands (such as cloning) get through the proxy fine. Which is what is leading me to think it's a Bower config issue, but I can't find a great deal of help on this.

Comment: Make sure that for any https proxy url, you are using an http url, not an https one: `https.proxy=http://127.0.0.1:53128/` (not `https://...`). Fix that, and see if that make a difference.

Comment: Hi @VonC, thanks for the suggestion, I've changed all these entries to http but unfortunately that hasn't solved the issue.

Comment: i see you are saying that raw git commands work; are you sure those commands are running over https?  I only ask because git works over ssh too and if you if you are running over ssh, it wont be effected by the proxy stuff.  Anyway, that might explain why raw git works but bower doesn't.

Comment: thanks for `"strict-ssl":false` you help me a lot :)

Answer (score 1):

in Windows cmd line i set my proxy environmental variables as so

```
> set https_proxy=http://10.1.56.10:80/   
> set http_proxy=http://10.1.56.10:80/
```

Then i as able to get my dependencies

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion, I have tried this but it didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

I was seeing a similar issue and found it was with the `.bowerrc` file.

I changed mine to be something like this and it worked fine:

```
{
    "proxy":"http://127.0.0.1:53128",
    "https-proxy":"http://127.0.0.1:53128",
    "registry": "http://bower.herokuapp.com",
    "strict-ssl":false
}
```